# Filtering list of objects

Tags: ecmascript-6, lodash

I rendered a list using Redux and there is a search field to find movies that include the search keyword. My list is an object not an array and if user types: "The" it should filter the list that has 'The' in the title.

```
{'1':  { 'title': 'A Name' },'2':  { 'title': 'The Name'  },'3':  { 'title': 'The Second Name'  }}
```

So the result after filter should be

```
{'2':  { 'title': 'The Name'  },'3':  { 'title': 'The Second Name'  }}
```

How would you do that? Using lodash is a bonus.
Thanks

Comment: The objects in your question are not valid. Could you make sure that you are giving the correct object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cay use [`_.pickBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#pickBy) as a filter for objects, check if each sub object title [`_.includes()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#includes) the search word:

```js
const data = {'1':  { 'title': 'A Name' }, '2':  { 'title': 'The Name'  }, '3':  { 'title': 'The Second Name'  }};

const result = _.pickBy(data, (v) => _.includes(v.title, 'The'));

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let filteredList = [];
    _.forEach(responseList, function(value) {
      var titleToSearch = value.title.split(" ");
      if(titleToSearch [0]=="The")
             filteredList.push(value);
    });
```

Kindly try this logic, have not tested though

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over your object keys, filter, and reduce result back to object.

```js
const obj = {'1':  { 'title': 'A Name' },'2':  { 'title': 'The Name'  },'3':  { 'title': 'The Second Name'  }}

console.log(
  Object.keys(obj)
    .filter(key => obj[key].title.includes('The'))
    .reduce((acc, key) => (acc[key] = obj[key], acc), {})
)
```

Or using lodash#transform

```js
const obj = {'1':  { 'title': 'A Name' },'2':  { 'title': 'The Name'  },'3':  { 'title': 'The Second Name'  }}

console.log(
  _.transform(obj, (result, value, key) => {
    if(value.title.includes('The')) result[key] = value
  }, {})
)
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/lodash@4.17.4"></script>
```